# ipsec google cloud server using 1 router which has been configured for failover between 2 ISPs

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform

I have 1 fortigate router in which failover has been created between 2 ISPs means if one ISP is down then internet will work using another ISP.the internal network ip pool of my office network is 192.168.0.0/24.i have created 2 vpn tunnel in google cloud server so that ipsec is connectable through individual ISP in case of down.But the problem here is i can access cloud server through Ipsec using primary ISP but not secondary ISP.I have created 1 route in cloud since the internal IP is of pool 192.168.0.0/24.I even tried creating 2 route with same ip ie 192.168.0.0/24 but it didn't work.i even tried policy based,routing based ipsec but it didn't work.So how can i make it possible to connect google cloud server by each ISP in case of ISP down?